# Rsyslog.conf delete, doesn't reinstall

Tags: logging

I have Ubuntu 18.04.  I am trying to set up rsyslog service as my default logging server.  I messed up configuration and didn't save a copy of the default file before modifying it.  I know, stupid.  I thought that if I remove the file and re-install rsyslog, default file will get recreated - It didn't. Can someone please suggest what to do in this situation?

Comment: Which file exactly did you motify?

Comment: System configuration files are not removed by default by `apt remove` - you need `purge` for that

Comment: rsyslog.conf is the rsyslog configuration file.  I wanted to load the default version of it that comes with first install of rsyslog service.  I thought that if i remove it (rm -rf /etc/rsyslog.com) and uninstall/reinstall rsyslog, the default rsyslog.conf file would be recreated but it didn't, now I have no way to configure the rsyslog service.

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew rsyslog`